# xserver-xorg-core update failed. Not fully installed or removed

Tags: apt, xorg, dpkg

I tried to update xserver by downloading `xserver-xorg-core_1.14.5-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb` from [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/xserver-xorg-core), and when I tried to install it it said:

```
(Reading database ... 266118 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace xserver-xorg-core 2:1.14.4.901+git20131203+server-1.14-branch.c30db601-0ubuntu0sarvatt4 (using xserver-xorg-core_1.14.5-1ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement xserver-xorg-core ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of xserver-xorg-core:
 xserver-xorg-core depends on xserver-common (>= 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2); however:
  Version of xserver-common on system is 2:1.14.4.901+git20131203+server-1.14-branch.c30db601-0ubuntu0sarvatt4.
 xserver-xorg-core depends on libgcrypt11 (>= 1.5.1); however:
  Version of libgcrypt11:amd64 on system is 1.5.0-3ubuntu3.

dpkg: error processing xserver-xorg-core (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 xserver-xorg-core
```

Now whenever I try to upgrade or install something it says:

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 xserver-xorg-core : Depends: xserver-common (>= 2:1.14.5-1ubuntu2) but 2:1.14.4.901+git20131203+server-1.14-branch.c30db601-0ubuntu0sarvatt4 is to be installed
                     Depends: libgcrypt11 (>= 1.5.1) but 1.5.0-3ubuntu3 is to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

When I do `sudo apt-get -f install` it says:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  ubuntu-desktop xorg xserver-xorg xserver-xorg-core xserver-xorg-input-all
  xserver-xorg-input-evdev xserver-xorg-input-mouse
  xserver-xorg-input-synaptics xserver-xorg-input-vmmouse
  xserver-xorg-input-wacom xserver-xorg-video-all xserver-xorg-video-ati
  xserver-xorg-video-cirrus xserver-xorg-video-fbdev xserver-xorg-video-intel
  xserver-xorg-video-mach64 xserver-xorg-video-mga
  xserver-xorg-video-modesetting xserver-xorg-video-neomagic
  xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-openchrome
  xserver-xorg-video-qxl xserver-xorg-video-r128 xserver-xorg-video-radeon
  xserver-xorg-video-s3 xserver-xorg-video-savage
  xserver-xorg-video-siliconmotion xserver-xorg-video-sis
  xserver-xorg-video-sisusb xserver-xorg-video-tdfx xserver-xorg-video-trident
  xserver-xorg-video-vesa xserver-xorg-video-vmware
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 33 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 13,0 MB disk space will be freed.
```

How to fix this issue ?

Please help me, I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem caused because that you are trying to install a package which is available in 14.04. The `xserver-xorg-core` version appropriate for 13.10 is `2:1.14.3` [See](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=saucy&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=xserver-xorg-core).

You can install `xserver-xorg-core` appropriate for your system by just typing :

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core
```

If you are still having the problem please add the output of :

```
apt-cache madison xserver-common
```

Comment: I have tried `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core`,but that gave an error: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/x4dun1LC). Here is the output of `apt-cache madison xserver-common`: [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/VhctAJhx). Also, is it possible that downloading and installing the correct xserver-xorg-core from the link you provided will fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: Allright, I solved it! I looked at the error messages and saw which version the old `xserver-xorg-core` was, and I looked on google on how to force a specific version when installing a package. So I did: `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-core=2:1.14.4.901+git20131203+server-1.14-branch.c30db601-0ubuntu0sarvatt4`, and it downgraded it to the old compatible version and now it works again!!! Yay!

Comment: I get: " libcheese-gtk23 : Depends: libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 (>= 0.91.8) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed libcheese7 : Depends: libclutter-gst-2.0-0 (>= 0.10.0) but it is not going to be installed Depends: gstreamer1.0-clutter but it is not going to be installed  libclutter-1.0-0 : Depends: libcogl-pango15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed Depends: libcogl15 (>= 1.15.8) but it is not going to be installed E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages." Any idea why?